# What am I missing having lost the Normandy's crew at the end of ME2?

Tags: mass-effect-3

At the end of Mass Effect 2 I completed the game with all squad mates alive, but all other crew members (except the doctor) dead. Now in ME3, the memorial wall on board the Normandy already contains numerous names, which I presume are referring to those crew members I failed to rescue (and Ashley from ME1).

Anyway, point is, my Normandy crew at the end of ME2 were lost, and at the start of ME3 I have a brand new crew.

Am I missing out on any potential war assets or misc. bonuses because I did not save the cerberus crew members in Mass Effect 2?

Comment: FWIW, the default (if you don't import the save) is for most of the characters to be dead anyway. For the most part you'll just see whatever living characters from before at one point or two in the game and they'll say something referencing the older games.

Comment: @One-One Check out this question http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19615/crew-at-the-end-of-mass-effect-2 which includes info about the crews' survival in with the rest of the info (the short version is: once the final mission appears, their survival depends on how many side and/or loyalty missions you do before starting it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not be able to get Engineers Donnely and Daniels, nor will Kelly Chambers be alive keep your fish safe (but you can re-buy them).

Everyone else doesn't come back.

Engineer Donnely and Daniels will eventually collaborate with Engineer Adams and give you the opportunity for a war asset. +30 I think?

Comment: Kelly doesn't even want to go on the ship, no matter what, she is replaced by a VI that takes care of them, for 25k credits

Comment: I never said Kelly wanted to go on the ship. I said if she's dead, she won't be able to give you back your fish.

Comment: i see what you did there

Comment: What did I do there???

Comment: Could you explain what bonus (if any) you get for having Engineers Donnely and Daniels alive in ME3? Are they War Assets or found on board the Normandy, etc?

Comment: @DMA57361 yes, if you do not get them, Daniels (I think? The girl, at any rate) will not give you her theory about Eezo Capacitors which is worth a small number of war assets. 25 I think? They join your crew down in engineering with Adams and Tali.

Comment: @DMA57361, if the engineers survive, you can pardon them at the Spectre terminal, and then they will give you a mission to make a small change to the Normandy's engines.  Obliging them unlocks a small war asset as a reward.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you will miss out on is a mission which you can go visit Kelly Chambers, and a chance to bring Engineer Ken Donnely and Engineer Gabby Daniels back onto the Normandy. The crew will be replaced anyways. You won't miss anything critical.