# Is it possible to complete all loyalty missions and save Kelly?

Tags: mass-effect-2

I'm playing through Mass Effect 2 again, and I've never figured out how to get everyone out of the suicide mission alive.  The Collectors always raid the Normandy when I've got one loyalty mission left to do (usually Legion's).

If I don't leave immediately after that, I arrive too late to save Kelly.  But if I don't have all the loyalty missions completed, one of the team ends up dead.  Is this a sadistic choice, like the Kaidan/Ashley thing from the first game, or is there a way to make sure everyone survives, including Kelly?

Comment: Perhaps some use of the spoiler markup would be a good idea on this question?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You need to finish all loyalty missions (except for Legion's) before going to the derelict Reaper. After getting back from the derelict Reaper, you are allowed time for exactly one mission before the Collectors invade Normandy (which should be Legion's loyalty mission). Once they've been removed from the ship, you must go directly to the Omega Relay if you want to save all of your crew.

Comment: I'm not sure if your'e allowed a single mission at all- but Legion's loyalty mission *is* the exception, and it will never trigger the boarding party.

Comment: @Raven I don't think I've ever tried to go anywhere but Legion's loyalty mission, so you could very well be right.

Comment: You are allowed two missions once you board the derelict before the raiding party hits.  I like taking Legion with me to Tali's loyalty mission. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's entirely possible to save absolutely everyone without completing every single loyalty mission - see also [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3978/how-do-i-earn-no-one-left-behind-with-as-few-squadmates-as-possible).

Answer (score 1):

After you get the IFF and legion you will be able to do 2, maybe 3 missions before the collectors attacked, to get everyone to survive, you must complete everyone's loyalty mission (except legion's which you can complete after), and use the Omega 4 relay just after the collector attack to have a chance at getting everyone out alive.

Answer (score 0):

I play it many times and after you recruit Legion, you have 2 missions left until the collectors raid the Normandy. I always leave just Tali's mission incomplete until I get Legion. I take him on her loyalty mission, then his(Legion) mission becomes available. After I do his mission, the collectors come. If you are in satisfied about your ending, save before you acquire the reaper IFF.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can but I highly suggest you activate Legion before accessing the galaxy map or the abduction will start and after do your loyalty for Legion at this point you lost half of your crew so yeah just after the Derelict Reaper mission activate Legion as fast as you can so you can do his LM before the crew's abduction hoped it helped

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer, but it's generally bad form to post a new answer which contains no new information, just the same as the already accepted one.