# Can I take Legion on Tali's loyalty mission, complete all loyalty missions (including his), and still save my whole crew?

Tags: mass-effect-2

In preparation for ME3, I'm doing a replay of *Mass Effect 2* and I want to know if I can take Legion on Tali's loyalty mission, complete all other loyalty missions (including his), and still save everyone in the crew.

I know at some point, my ship gets invaded and collectors make off with a lot of my crew. I also know that there's some sort of timing mechanic built into the game where if I take too long after a trigger event (which is probably that same event... the crew being kidnapped... but maybe not, I don't know), some or all of them will be dead by the time I find them on the other side of the Omega IV relay.

I've read [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/19695/3062) and [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/27147/3062) but they just seem like pieces of the puzzle. I want the full picture.

- What triggers my crew being kidnapped?
- Is Legion's loyalty mission a special case that doesn't count as a mission on **The Crew** section of [this chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9Lvn.jpg)? Are there any other special cases? Is that bit of the chart actually right?

As I said, the main reason I'd like to know all this is that, if possible, I'd like to get Legion in my party, take him on Tali's loyalty mission (because bringing a Geth to the Quarian flotilla sounds potentially hilarious), do his and every other loyalty mission, and still save my entire crew. I can't deduce the steps I'd need to take to accomplish this from the other related questions because I don't have a full understanding of what the trigger events are. Is it possible, and if so, how do I do it?

Comment: You definitely can, but I'm a bit fuzzy on remembering the details (yx.'s answer sounds about right, though). "because bringing a Geth to the Quarian flotilla sounds potentially hilarious" - This leads to some pretty interesting conversation options, heh.

Comment: Taking Legion with me to Tali's quest was one of the most entertaining things I've done in the game that's for sure.

Comment: Definitely bring Legion

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can perform all the loyalty missions, take Legion on Tali's loyalty mission, and save your entire crew if you do the following:

1. Do everything but Tali's loyalty mission.
2. Do the mission to obtain the Reaper IFF.
3. Do Tali's loyalty mission.
4. Do Legion's loyalty mission.
5. At this point, you should actually be out of things to do, and you'll be wondering why the Collectors haven't attacked yet. Go click your galaxy map. This should trigger the Collector invasion.
6. Once it is over, go straight through the Omega IV relay. You don't have anything else left to do anyway!

Comment: The other two answers disagreed on minor points and I can't verify one over the other as correct, which is why I wrote up my eventual experience. But credit to them for letting me know it was possible.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that you can make 3 jumps with the Normandy once you obtain the Reaper IFF before the collector attack.  So it should be possible to obtain Legion, jump straight to Tali's loyalty mission, and then immediately do Legion's mission.

Once the crew is abducted, its uncertain how many more missions you can do before half the crew dies, but general consensus seems to be 1-3 missions.

[This link](http://www.supercheats.com/guides/mass-effect-2/reaper-iff/) seems to imply that its possible but just to be sure you should save before obtaining the Reaper IFF.

Comment: [According to the Wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Stop_the_Collectors#Await_IFF_Installation), once the crew is abducted, you have to go immediately if you want to save all of them. The 1-3 missions figure is if you want to save only half of the crew. However, I think you should have enough time to do both loyalty missions between obtaining the IFF and the abduction, though it's not clear exactly what triggers the IFF installation (except that it triggers immediately if you have no more missions left, giving you just enough time for Legion's mission before the abduction).

Comment: @yx. I've now completed this. I can't verify the rest of your answer (like getting 3 jumps after picking up the IFF), but I did everything but Tali's loyalty mission before doing the IFF mission. I was then able to do Tali's loyalty mission followed by Legion's loyalty mission. Once that was done, I had literally nothing left to do, and the next time I used my nav map, the collector attack was triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's what I know: The "trigger event" is the Reaper IFF mission, we've got that point covered. After doing this mission (and acquiring Legion, of course), you have time to do **exactly two missions** before the Collectors attack. After the Collector attack, you have to rush to the Omega4-relay in case you want to save all the crew; doing one single mission is already enough to kill some of them, although I'm not sure how many.

Just to give some inspiration: my next attempt in my ME2-playthrough is to recruit Tali **after** getting Legion and taking him with me on the recruitment mission. Because I want to save all my crew ('cause I'm a fuckin' hero), that means that I'll be only able to do one of the loyality missions, either Legion's or Tali's. And because I really like Tali and want to have her as my romance, I'll do her's and try to bring Legion through the suicide mission without killing him, which, in theory, shouldn't be that big a problem. (Safest way probably is to send him back with the crew, for we already made the way clear, and he shouldn't have much trouble. He's quite a fighter, after all.)

Only I'm not sure if I'll even get the conversation option to trigger the romance... but hell, try and error, I guess. I'll let you know if it worked.

Comment: FWIW, if you send an unloyal person back with the crew they will die.

Comment: If you wish to do this: never recruit Kasumi and take Tali and Mordin with you on the final mission. Never select Legion as a specialist. If my math is correct, this should give you JUST enough firepower during the Holding the Line segment (22 troop value on 11 troops) to allow everyone to survive. If you recruit Kasumi, she has a very weak troop value (1), and not having Legion's loyalty means he also only has 1, which means your troop rating is 23/12, which is just below the 2.0 average needed to make everyone survive. I think it'll also ruin chances of Geth/Quarian peace in ME3.

Answer (score -2):

***3 things you need to have before entering the omega 4 relay: thanix canon, heavy ship damage, and multi-core shielding upgrades.***

**Easiest way to obtain the upgrades is using the upgrade terminal in Mordins lab rather than talking to each team member and asking them for upgrades.**

Also you must go thru the omega 4 relay as soon as it opens or crew members will die.

And you have exactly 2 missions before the collectors board the Normandy after going to the derelict reaper.

Before going to the derelict reaper you just need to do all the recruitments and loyalty missions and then go to the derelict reaper where you obtain the reaper iff and gain legion for your team if you want him.(completing the loyalty missions will also ensure you to have either full paragon or renegade, but make sure you try to lean one direction for at least a good portion of the game, or you won’t be able to keep certain members of your team loyal even after completing their loyalty missions). Then go to legion immediately upon arriving back on the Normandy(also make sure you save as soon as you get back to the Normandy). Then after your dialogue ends with legion the first time walk back up to him again to get the loyalty mission right off the top. Go and do his loyalty mission and then head to the omega 4 relay.  If all the members of your team are loyal you have nothing to worry about and make sure you slide the crew into their proper roles, if they ask you for an engineer send in either tali or legion if they ask for a leader send in Miranda or Garrus  Leave grunt, Garrus, and zaeed to stay and hold down the fort when asked, so to speak. And send Samara as the powerful biotic protector against the bugs from hell. When you rescue the abducted crew members send Mordin with them because he’s good at keeping people alive, but make sure you send someone with them or either Chakwas or Kelly will die..if I’m remembering correctly. If you do these things your crew will live and you’ll gain the achievement, “No one left behind”.

Good luck and God speed soldier you’ve got a lot of work to do. lol I’ve been playing this game too much lately.