# Can I safely complete all assignments after the final mission?

Tags: mass-effect-2

I'm currently working on my second playthrough of Mass Effect 2. In the first, I skipped the N7 and DLC assignments because I wanted to save them for my completionist playthrough (this one). I'm currently planning on doing them after I finish the final mission, however, I want to make sure that I'm not going to end up with any of them locked out or blocked because of changing circumstances after you finish the main story.

If I decide to wait to complete these assignments until after the going through the Omega 4 Relay and beating the final boss, will I still be able to complete them all?

Comment: Based on the current answer (but contrary to its conclusion), I assume if you [make the right decisions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3978/how-do-i-earn-no-one-left-behind-with-as-few-squadmates-as-possible) on the other side of the Omega 4 Relay there's nothing that would prevent you from finishing up the DLC assignments...but I'm not positive.

Comment: For a completionist run, I would recommend doing all side missions before going after the Reaper IFF, since at that point you can delay the main story indefinitely without any consequences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a possibility of locking yourself out of some things here:

> If you somehow do not survive the suicide attack, your game will end after the final mission, so you will not be able to complete anything else after that.
>  
>  If you did not do the loyalty missions of a few followers and they die on the suicide mission, then you will not be able to finish their quests afterwards.
>  
>  If you somehow ran out of money and can't buy fuel, you won't be able to visit sectors not containing a mass relay.

Other than that, after the suicide mission you will be placed back in your ship and have the chance to explore and do whatever you want.  Some DLCs, such as the Shadowbroker, actually makes more sense to complete after the suicide mission since the dialog is geared towards that.

Comment: But Shadow Broker can be so useful before the suicide mission (namely resource rich planets and shipments).

Comment: @MBraedley Having indulged in my OCD tendencies during my latest ME2 playthrough, I can say with certainty that the Shadow Broker planet resources are absolutely unnecessary and probably not even particularly helpful. I depleted every planet in the game and after all upgrades, had ~1 million of every resource except Element Zero, which was at ~200k.

Comment: @Sterno: Yes, but some of us don't have such extreme OCD and actually want to get on with the story and not spend endless hours playing a mini-game that isn't really all that fun.

Comment: @MBraedley I agree, and I hope no one else does what I did! My point was really just that the galaxy has an overabundance of resources, even before the DLC.

Comment: The dialog in the Shadow Broker DLC changes slightly if you play it before or after the final mission. Very nice touch.