# Can I get Legion early and still save the crew?

Tags: mass-effect-2

I'm now at my third play through of Mass Effect 2 and this time I decided to take Legion with me on more missions. However, doing lots of missions after Legion joined means the Normandy Crew will die, which is mildly annoying.

Is there any way to prevent this?

(Since, according to [this question's](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52594/can-i-take-legion-on-talis-loyalty-mission-complete-all-loyalty-missions-incl) answers, it's not possible, I don't mind modding, exploiting a glitch, editing my save file or cheating)

According to [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/53035/56985) I can complete most missions after completing the main quest, but I still would have to do loyalty mission without legion.

Comment: You would be able to use Gibbed to edit whether or not Legion is in your group - maybe it's possible to edit him into your save this way so you've not triggered the "3 jump" constraint after getting the IFF but I haven't tested this.

Comment: I will try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Legion to your squad through Gibbed before obtaining the IFF. (thanks kalina for the hint).

In my play-through I did not encounter any glitches or ill effects.
However:

1. You miss out on some dialog you'd normally get by talking to Legion just after recruiting him
2. You might want to remove Legion from your Squad with Gibbed before obtaining the IFF. Nothing game-breaking happens if you don't, just some minor inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the mentioned Gibbed to edit the number of assignments taken after collectors attack on the Normandy. Go for quests and adventures and try reset the number of taken assignments to 0 before going through Omega 4 relay. Although I didn't try it myself yet.

Comment: I didn't find the variable corresponding to the number of assignments, do you have the exact name?