# Mass Effect 2: Delay Reaper IFF Instalation

Tags: mass-effect-2

I wanted to play Mass Effect 2 again but now picking different options and morale.

But I forgot about the internal countdown do Omega 4 Relay that, according to wiki, is [randomly computed based on number of available missions](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Stop_the_Collectors#Await_IFF_Installation) which, I think, start counting from the moment I give EDI an OK to proceed with IFF install.

So, I was going on with my playthrough, went to Tali's Trial at Migrant Fleet (for which I took Legion as second squadmate - I wanted to watch the world burn) and after that, while finishing some planet explorations, suddenly, I was interrupted by the main questline with Collectors invasion and crew abductions.

And here starts the problem. Although I'm playing to be a ruthless renegade, I want everyone alive but I can't complete even one single mission prior to go through Omega 4 relay, otherwise, as well known, Kelly Chambers (and half of the crew) would die.

I don't have ME2 DLCs, not other than the ones included in trilogy box, the one I bought. I was planning to buy them next Monday but before doing so I would like to know if with this little number of remaining missions available before abductions, I'll be able to complete all the questline of all worth to get DLCs.

If not, is there anything else I can do, even if I have to use Gibbe ME2 Save Editor, or rollback prior to Reaper IFF acquisition is my only solution?

Comment: Where do you get that it's random?  Pretty sure it's all based on specific missions.

Comment: Check the link I've added. Specifically, it's two paragraphs above Joker's picture. It's not explicit it's random but the number of available quests at time of Reaper IFF acquisition is by definition a random parameter so...

Comment: I still don't think it's random, it's just that the wiki doesn't say.  Besides, if you have that many missions left, frankly, you're doing it wrong or have an interesting reason for wanting Legion so early.

Comment: That's the point. I didn't have that much as it may sound. After acquire the IFF I only needed to recruit Tali and do her and Legion's loyalty missions. But because I don't know exactly what I'll have after install the DLCs I don't have, I wasn't sure about have enough time to finish them all (even I knowing I can finish other things after the Suicide Mission).

Comment: You don't have to play the DLCs before doing the final mission. Once the final mission is completed, you are back on your ship and you can freely explore the galaxy to do any missions you haven't finished yet (including DLC).

Comment: Although I knew that, I guess you're right. Sigh... My thoughts were about changes in Suicide Mission with the DLCs (no spoilers, please). I think I'll find out in the worst of the moments: An Insanity replay. Thank you. And you to, Braedley.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under certain circumstances you can complete one mission after the crew is taken - hopefully, it will be Legion's loyalty mission. The trick here is to make sure you've talked to Legion enough so that you get his loyalty mission *and* it's in your logs before you touch the galaxy map. If his mission is in there before the crew is abducted, you are able to do that mission, get him loyal, and then save everyone and not just half. Him and Tali, though, I'm not so sure.

See, my MO is to get everything possible done before going to get the IFF, so that all I have to do is say hi to Legion, and then again when he asks me for help. I do this *before* using the galaxy map after EDI says the IFF has been installed. Sure, it means Legion isn't around for much, which sucks, but at least I save the crew (and if I want to bring him on DLC jaunts, I can do that after the suicide mission).

There shouldn't be too many (if any) alterations to be made vis a vis the DLC and the suicide mission. Sure, if someone's dead then you'll miss out on whatever lines they or someone referring to them might have had, but if, say, Garrus is dead you'll still be able to complete all the DLC. You will be super-sad, however, because Garrus will be dead and that's terrible beyond words. Don't kill Garrus.

As for doing the DLC before the suicide mission, as mentioned above if you do those after the IFF you're asking for your crew to get vaped. All of it can wait until after the mission, or you can do it first thing in another run-through. There are very few functional differences in the endgame with or without DLC.

**SO:** If you've already lost the crew but you still have Tali and Legion's loyalty missions to do, you either sacrifice half of the crew for loyal members, or you take a chance and hope everyone else's loyalty will keep them alive (don't pick those two for anything special, for example). Installing the DLC will not make a difference in the number of missions allowed before the crew dies, it just gives you more overall to do that does not significantly impact anything outside of the overall storyline and your enjoyment of the game.

(I realize that was a lot of text and probably a bit repetitious. You might be able to fiddle with Gibbed, but I'm not sure what specifically you'd have to change. Someone else may have figured that out.)

(What you can do in future games is fiddle with Gibbed so that teammates like Tali and Legion are available right away. You can't go and talk with them on the ship, I don't think, but you can use them in missions as they'll show up as available in the team selection screen. It's how people are able to make gameplay videos showing what Samara et al say in certain instances, like when you're going to get Jack and that prisoner is getting beaten.)

Basically, ah, you're probably going to want to go back to a different save. :(
[Here is a link to a question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/134044/can-i-get-legion-early-and-still-save-the-crew?rq=1) that may be relevant to your concerns as well. [Here's another relevant question and answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52594/can-i-take-legion-on-talis-loyalty-mission-complete-all-loyalty-missions-incl?rq=1) that also has an explanation of what you can do and still save your crew.

Comment: Nice answer. In this meanwhile I loaded a previous save just in case to complete the DLCs (Arrival was awfully hard). Now I'm replaying for Insanity. Although the problem was already solved in comments, I'll mark your answer as accepted not only because it's the only one but also because it's very well formulated.

Comment: Hooray! And I'm glad you're having fun. I've never taken the time to do an Insanity run, mainly because I'd probably drive myself insane with some of the fights (like that one in Arrival where you get an achievement for staying up through all the waves).

Comment: That achievement I've completed in Normal mode and was tough. I don't know why but I'm thinking this Insanity playthrough is being way more easier this time, maybe because I already played Insanity before and now I'm taking better squad choices than I did in past.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the top answer there is a serious problem with having neither Tali nor Legion loyal as they are the only two people who can complete the first section of the collector base without being killed and that is only when they are loyal.

Comment: For the context of this question this is not correct, because like I said I didn't have any of the four worth to buy DLCs, now I do, and one of them provided me Kasumi Goto as permanent squadmate, and she is also a tech expert to go in the vent tunnels (in fact I choosed her when finishing the Normal playthrough). But it's a perfect valid point the one you raised, though.

Comment: fair point i don't have any of that DLC and hadn't considered it

Comment: When I bought the trilogy about an year ago I thought I wouldn't need or want them. Although simple, they add things you don't usually expect in ME2 context. Without spoilers, Arrival is the most difficult, even on Normal.

Comment: I hadn't wanted to mention Kasumi above, since you said no spoilers, but I'm glad you have her because not only is she acceptable as a tech expert but she's hilarious and introduces you to the gun that killed two presidents. Zaeed's just a delightful crusty tank.

Comment: I didn't like too much in using Zaeed, but he's almost vital in early stages on Insanity because of his grenades. Kasumi is great because of (Deadly) Shadow Strike and her "ha-ha".

Comment: i appear to have got an upvote for admitting i cocked up, not sure where that came from